# How do I include a comma in a Regex expression?

Tags: regex, fish

I started using fish today, and am using `sed` to search for:

```
}\n
```

I want to replace it with:

```
},\n
```

I tried

```
`sed -i -- 's/}\n/},\n/g' EU_Users.json`
```

but when I checked the file there were no commas present.

How can I add them in?

Comment: That did it! Add it as an answer an I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that `sed` does not add `\n` to the pattern space by default, it uses newlines to split a stream into lines.

You may use

```
sed -i -- 's/}$/},/' EU_Users.json
```

The `}$` will match a `}` at the end of the line (`$`) and these matches will be replaced with `},`.

Note that `g` modifier is not necessary: `sed` will process line after line, and since there is only one end of a line in each line, we only need a single search and replace operation.

Comment: This is very helpful - thank you. Building on that, could I use a similar cal lto search for the final comma in the same document and replace it with a `]`?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy Yes, `sed -i -- 's/,$/]/' file` (if you mean commas at the end of  lines).

Comment: Almost, but it doesn't remove the final comma.

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/bBYKsi). Though there is Bash there, that is how `sed` should work.

Comment: I'll take a look. In fact, that code applied a `]` at the end of _every_ line - can it be applied only to the final line so that the last character (a comma) is replaced by it?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy Yeah, use `sed '$ s/,$/]/'`

Comment: Awesome, that did it! I asked a separate question for this but please add the answer there and I will accept. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779284/how-can-i-replace-the-final-character-in-a-document-with-a

Comment: Your answers proved very helpful, so I have accepted and upvoted both accordingly. Thanks again.