# How can I replace the final character in a document with a ]?

Tags: fish

How can I replace the final character of a file with a `]`?

For example, if the document content looked like this:

```
This is the first line with a full stop.
This is the second line with a full stop.
This is the third line with square bracket.
```

I would want it to look like this afterwards:

```
This is the first line with a full stop.
This is the second line with a full stop.
This is the third line with square bracket]
```

Comment: The commas are added in after the file is generated.  I have to go through a series of steps to prepare the file to be handled in R and this is the final step.

Comment: In it's most basic form, the filetype is irrelevant here.  All I want to do is replace the final character of a file with a `]`. I'll update the question accordingly to make is easier for people to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may specify line numbers, ranges or even the last line where you want to perform search and replace operations with `sed`:

This will replace the final `,` char with `]` *only* on the last line:

```
sed '$ s/,$/]/'
```

Here, the `$` char tells `sed` to only replace on the last line.

The `sed '1 s/,$/]/'` command will do that only on Line 1, and `sed '1,4 s/,$/]/'` will do that on lines 1 through 4.